# UIImageView setHighlightedImage: does it have to be on main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiimageview, uikit

I'm working to improve the performance of images displayed to the user. I have removed alpha blending and am assigning a scaled/correctly sized image to the UIImageView already along with some caching. However, also as a part of this I am thinking of moving `setHiglightedImage:` call to background thread.

ImageView is wrapped in UIKit which says that any modification to layouts should be done on main thread. However while assigning an image with a highlightedImage we're not triggering any layout changes or invoking any constraints. Would this be a valid change that doesn't violate UIKit rules? Are there going to be any exceptions thrown because of this?

I don't see any problems or warnings by debugger while running this so far on background thread. Also the apple's official documentation ([here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageview) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageview/1621066-highlightedimage)) around UIImageView doesn't specify anything about this being on background thread. I tried searching more online about doing this, but couldn't really find anything helpful

**Is there any reason for** `[UIImageView setHighlightedImage:]` **to not be on background thread?** Will it have any performance benefits?

Answer (score 1):

**setHighlightedImage** is changing the **user interface** . You can not run it on a background thread.

> In a Cocoa application, **the main thread runs the user interface**, that
>   is, all drawing and all events are handled on the main thread. If your
>   application performs any lengthy synchronous operations on that
>   thread, your user interface can become unresponsive and trigger the
>   spinning cursor. To avoid this, you should shorten the amount of time
>   consumed by those operations, defer their execution, or move them to
>   secondary threads.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaPerformance/Articles/UnblockUI.html)